# Accessing instance variables of a class from pybind11 wrappers

Tags: c++, pybind11

I haven't found a way to do a fairly simple thing with pybind11. Suppose I have an aggregated class, and I want to get to an instance variable of a class so I can drill down into it:

```
struct foo {
  int x;
};

struct baz {
  foo var;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(test, m) {
  py::class_<baz>(m, "baz")
  .def(py::init<>())
  .def("GetX", /* need a lambda to return var.x */ )
  ;
}
```

I haven't found anything in the docs which does this, and it seems like an obvious thing to do. I could create accessor methods in baz, but that is extra work. I'd like to do it in a lambda in the wrapper code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lambda creates the necessary `GetX` member function, which expects one argument: a `baz` instance. The argument is supplied by pybind11 when `GetX` is called on an instance of the wrapper class.

```
  ...
  .def("GetX", [](const baz &b) { return b.var.x; });
```

Usage:

```
>>> import ex
>>> v = ex.baz()
>>> v.GetX()
0
```

See also the pybind11 doc section on [binding lambda functions](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#binding-lambda-functions).

Comment: Is that first instance argument to the lambda function always supplied when a .def statement provides a lambda instead of a pointer to an existing method of the class?

Comment: As far as I can tell: yes.